What do you call a 'slot' of a class?
For example, in the sentence "There are no slots available for this class", or if you wanted to put in a table.



Class
Slots Available




Chemistry
10


Physics
24



Is 'slot' the correct term?

Does this mean that up to 10 students can choose to do chemistry?  I'd use "places".

I think we generally say "seat". "There are 20 seats available in this class." Or you could say "student", with words such as "space for" or "room for", as in, "This class has space for 20 students."
You could say "slot", though as @jamesmathai says, a "slot" could also refer to a time slot. You'd have to make clear which you mean.
